# How to number sections of the Appendix if numbering is suppressed by the document class (like apa6)

Tags: numbering, appendices, apa6

The question is simple as always with numbering: I would like to number sections as Appendix A, Appendix B... and its subsections as A.1, A.2... But the normal commands for changing it seem to be suppressed by the document class [apa6]. A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{apa6}
\begin{document}
{\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\section{Title}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\subsection{Title}
}
\end{document}
```

I suppose that, although this problem is due to the apa6 class, it may reproduce in any document class which imposes its numbering rules. I suppose this problem also concerns the main text.

Comment: A look into `apa6.cls` file reveals, that neither `\thesection` etc. commands are ever used, unfortunately, so you can redefine them to whatever you want, it won't work! Using this `.cls` file locks many features actually, is it necessary to use that class?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes: it is a .cls required for many journals in physiology. Although normally they do not require numbering. So, if I am right, there is no choice but to define the counters myself if the class file does not do it?

Comment: Unfortunately,  defining counters not used by the cls code is useless. I would rather suggest to use the article or book class and adapt some settings to make it look like `apa6`

Comment: You can redefine \thepage every time you change "sections".

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\thepage` is not the point at all. You could do anything with the `\thepage`, but as the `section` command does not call it explicitly it is of no use here, besides it would lead to inconsistent page numbering output if not redefined to the correct form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counters are already there, but `\secnumdepth` has been set to `0` suppressing them.  Additionally in the Appendix, the `subsection` counter needs to be reset at each appendix.  Issuing

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{subsection}{appendix}\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\theappendix.\arabic{subsection}}
```

does this and provides the desired format for the subsection numbers.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{apa6}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text

\begin{document}
\section{Body section}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Body subsection}

\lipsum[2]

{\appendix\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{subsection}{appendix}\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\theappendix.\arabic{subsection}}

\section{Appendix section}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Appendix section}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\lipsum[2]
}
\end{document}
```